# how to get fourier transform of a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, wavelet

In the below code I am trying to get the `fourier transform` of a stationary signal (x3). But at run time the plot i get is absolutely something wrong and does not show any frequencies of the signals x3.

kindly please guide me and help me to get the `fourier transform` correctly.

***Code***:

```
 %% Time specifications:
  Fs = 8000;                       % samples per second
  dt = 1/Fs;                       % seconds per sample
 StopTime = 1;                    % seconds
 t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt);         % seconds

 x1 = (10)*cos(2*pi*3*(t));
 x2 = x1 + (10)*cos(2*pi*5*(t));
 x3 = x2 + (10)*cos(2*pi*10*(t));


 %% here i try to Plot fourier transform of the signal x3:
 NFFT = 2^nextpow2(StopTime); % Next power of 2 from length of y
 Y = fft(y,NFFT)/StopTime;
 f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
 figure;
 plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)));

 %% Plot the signal versus time:
 figure;
 hold on;
 plot(t,x1,'r');
 plot(t,x2,'g');
 plot(t,x3,'b');
```

**Update_1**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you scaling the FFT with `StopTime`? If you want the energy in time domain to equal the energy in frequency domain, you would have to scale by `Fs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not see what you expected because the value of `NFFT` is `1` means when you write `NFFT/2+1` as an index of `Y` it will not be an integer value so MATLAB warns you. You can calculate `NFFT` like this:

```
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(length(t))
```

instead of writing

```
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(StopTime)
```

Well, try this:

```
Fs       = 8000;                 % samples per second
dt       = 1/Fs;                 % seconds per sample
StopTime = 1;                    % seconds
t        = (0 : dt : StopTime-dt);   % seconds

x1 = 10 * cos(2*pi*3*t);
x2 = x1 + 10 * cos(2*pi*5*t);
x3 = x2 + 10 * cos(2*pi*10*t);


%% here i try to Plot fourier transform of the signal x3:
NFFT = 2 ^ nextpow2(length(t));     % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y    = fft(x3, NFFT) / StopTime;
f    = Fs / 2 * linspace(0, 1, NFFT/2 + 1);
figure;
plot(f, 2 * abs( Y( 1:length(f) ) ) ); % // Also try this: plot(f(f <= 200), 2 * abs( Y( 1:length(f(f <= 200)) ) ) )

%% Plot the signal versus time:
figure;
hold on;
plot(t, x1, 'r');
plot(t, x2, 'g');
plot(t, x3, 'b');
```

**Plots:**

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

**1-** Actually you don' t have to use `nextpow()` function. If you use it, `fft()` function works faster. Because, due to time efficiency, `fft()` works like that recursively divide the signal by 2 for each time. Then calculates discrete fourier transform for each part and gather them. This means that the FFT is most efficient when the signal vector length is a power of 2.

**2-** Dividing fft result by `StopTime` part doesn' t make any sense to me either. Dividing fft result by `NFFT` may be more convenient theoretically.

Comment: thank you for the answer. now in the freq. domain, the plot statemnt plot(f, 2 * abs( Y( 1:length(f) ) ) ); generates a graph from zero-4000 on the x-axis. how can i minimize the values on the x-axis to be for an example from 0-200.

Comment: one more question please, why do i need the function nextpow2() i read about in the docs but why do i need it? and why you divided by StopTime in this statement: fft(x3, NFFT) / StopTime

Comment: You can write "plot(f(f <= 200), 2 * abs( Y( 1:length(f(f <= 200)) ) ) )"

Comment: i wish you saw my questions to you in my previous comment :)

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, kindly please have a look at my update of the question and notice the difference in freq. presentation when i divide by NFFT and when it is ignored.

Comment: @user2121 - You see, the amplitude values make more sense when you divide fft result by NFFT, wrt analytical solution. Spikes look wider place in frequency axis when you divide but actually it is the same with when you dont divide due to scale of amplitute you can not see. You can see there is no differense if you zoom in..